# Why does this sometimes print "Leap year" twice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, leap-year

This code is for a leap year calculator/identifier assignment I had. While I passed it, I was wondering why it printed "Leap year" twice depending on some years. Sometimes it did, sometimes it didn't depending on the host I was using, eg. Thonny, Coding Rooms, replit.

Here is my code:

```
year = int(input("Which year do you want to check? "))

if year%4==0:
    if year%100==0:
        if year%400==0:
            print("Leap year")
        else:
            print("Not leap year")
        print("Leap year")
    else:
        print("Not leap year")
else:
    print("Not leap year")
```

Comment: You print it twice if the year is divisible by 100 and 400. Can you see why?

Comment: We can tell you what's wrong but you'll learn more if you debug this yourself. What you can do is first figure out an example year that's causing double printouts; then trace through the logic and identify where the code going awry.

Comment: For which input did it print `Leap year` twice?

Answer (score 1):

If it is divided by 100 and 400 in your case, it will print that it is leap year.

Because it will go into the year%100 and then into if year%400 and will print leap year.
Then it will go to the next statement after the else of year%400 and it will print it again. (the parts between **)

```
if year%100==0:
        if year%400==0:
            **print("Leap year")**
        else:
            print("Not leap year")
        **print("Leap year")**
```

Answer (score 0):

it print "Leap year" twice because you added unimportant line 8,you can simplify your code by writing just one if statement to check if it is a leap year or not,

```
def isLeapYear(year):
    return year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0
```